# Unable to call Struts2 action in Liferay6.2 Struts2 Portlet

Tags: jsp, struts2, liferay-6, portlet, struts2-jquery

Overview: Trying to port a struts2 webapp into Liferay 6.2 Struts2 Portlet.

Problem definition: The action mentioned in struts.xml is not called and the url which is formed is not the url to my newly created portlet.
This can be explained as per below example:

jsp Page:

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

<br>
<s:if test="%{xyz!= null}">
 <br />
  <div style="margin-left:9em;">
   <s:property value="xyz" escapeHtml="false"/>
  </div>
 <br /><br />
</s:if>
<br>

<br />

<sj:tabbedpanel id="billTab" >
    <sj:tab id="overview" href="%{overviewURL}" label="Overview"
            target="overviewDiv" indicator="loadingInd" />
    <sj:tab id="invoices" href="%{invoiceURL}" label="Invoices" 
            target="invoicesDiv" indicator="loadingInd" />
    <div id="overviewDiv" ></div>
    <div id="invoicesDiv" ></div>

</sj:tabbedpanel>
```

In the above jsp , there is a `sj:tabbedpanel` panel, in which there is a `href="%{overviewURL}"`, this href forms a GET request like below :

```xml
abc.com/web/billOverview?billId=37527220&bcrumId=34566&billTo=abc`
```

and NOT LIKE a portlet request with portletid like below:

> abc.com/web/billToCustomer?p_auth=f7WFYwgJ&p_p_auth=DR6ptk9Y&p_p_id=adminportlet_WAR_Portlet10SNAPSHOT&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_adminportlet_WAR_Portlet10SNAPSHOT_templateDir=template&_adminportlet_WAR_Portlet10SNAPSHOT_theme=simple&_adminportlet_WAR_Portlet10SNAPSHOT_dynamicAttributes=%7B%7D&_adminportlet_WAR_Portlet10SNAPSHOT_id=selectSiteForm&D&_adminportlet_WAR_Portlet10SNAPSHOT_struts.portlet.action=%2Fportal%2FbillOverview&_adminportlet_WAR_Portlet10SNAPSHOT_struts.portlet.mode=view

Due to this my action "billOverview" defined in struts.xml is not called .should I be using something like `portlet:actionURL` to form the url instead ? How to implement in this case .please help.

Comment: Where this `overviewURL` is coming from? Have you tried with `<s:url>` tag? And don't get confused by the way portlet url-s look like, they supposed to be different.

Comment: overviewURL is coming from the Action Class , where it is getting populated in a method name : setUpUrl() , which forms different urls like overviewURL, invoiceURL, etc. I have not used <s:url> tag

Comment: Show the URL(s) you are creating in the action class

Comment: Which version of S2 jquery plugin are you using?

Comment: Try to escape `&` in the url.

Comment: How would I use <s:url> tag here, please advise!
Something like : 

<sj:tab id="overview" href="<s:url action="billOverview" portletUrlType="action" />"label="Overview"
            target="overviewDiv" indicator="loadingInd" />

Comment: url is build by below line:

`code` StringBuilder  overviewURL = new StringBuilder("billOverview")
          .append(Constants.BILLING_ACCOUNT_ID).append("=")
          .append(accountId).append("&bcrumId").append("=").append(breadCrmbId);

Comment: struts2-jquery-plugin - version : 3.4.0

Comment: @RKGupta: Have you tried to escape `&` in your url?

Comment: You need a plugin for liferay, did you try searching the plugin registry?

Comment: didnt helped Aleksandr ... :(
Still unable to invoke my action , it says resource not available.

Comment: which plugin are you talking about Roman C? All the plugins are already in place ..I have created the portlet using the Liferay plugin for eclipse.

Comment: What about liferay-struts2 plugin?

Comment: @RKGupta: It could be a problem with S2 jquery plugin. Try creating url not in `<sj:tab>` tag.

Comment: *liferay S2 plugin* :).

Comment: @RomanC: I am using struts2-jquery-plugin - version : 3.4.0

Comment: @AleksandrM: Just wanted to add that, I was having an issue where I was getting "Tiles IO/Free Marker Exception" on load of the portlet. So I had found a solution in which I have modified the struts2-jquery-plugin by modifying a line in /templates/head.ftl file .I found the solution here in the following link: [https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/issues/detail?id=949]

I hope this has not cause the issue.

Comment: @AleksandrM: .. using `<s:url/>` outside the <sj:tab> and I refered the <s:url/> using its id field inside the <sj:tab> worked and did form the required portlet request and hence called the struts action..brilliant!thanks a ton!

Comment: So it is some issue with S2 jquery plugin. BTW use `var` attribute of `<s:url>` tag instead of `id`.

Comment: @AleksandrM Also how do I use `var` in the `<s:url/>` tag ?
I have used something like :
`<s:url id="billOverview" action="%{overviewURL}" portletMode="view" portletUrlType="struts.portlet.action" />`

Comment: @TechieTalk: `<s:url var="billOverview" .../>` because `id` is deprecated.